# CodeIgniter: adding a $subresult to an object $result by an ActiveRecord result ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, activerecord

I'm having issues adding a "sub result" to a result in Codeigniter.  Not sure how to add to this object.

---

```
$result->{$record_id}->threads = $threads;
```

should equal something like this

```
$result->1->threads = $threads;
```

but I can't get it to work...  I'm not new to OOP but this is the first I've tried to do this.

```
<?php

function get() {

 $this->db->select(array(

  'record_id',  'record_data',  'record_date',

 ));

 $this->db->from('records');

 $sql   = $this->db->get();
 $records  = $sql->result();

 foreach($records as $record){

  $record_id = $record->record_id;

  $this->db->select(array(

   'thread_id',   'thread_parent',   'thread_data',    'thread_date',

  ));

  $this->db->from('records_thread');
  $this->db->where(array(

   'thread_recordid'  => $record_id,

  ));

  $sql   = $this->db->get();
  $threads = $sql->result();

  # this is where i'm having issues \/

  $records->{$record_id}->threads = $threads;

 }

 return $records;

}
?>
```

I don't want to use arrays and it's easier to use this data on the view file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need:

```
$record->threads = $threads;
```

EDIT:

You just need to assign the reference in your foreach (note the `&` next to `$record`):

```
foreach($records as &$record)
{
    //...
    $record->threads = $threads;
}

return $records;
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this works. If I had to guess, I'd imagine it doesn't, simply because I'd assume PHP isn't creating a pointer to the original object on each foreach loop. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Yeah this doesn't attach to each record by ID.  It just simply creates a separate object element.

Comment: @jhat - that separate object element is attached to the record in $records that has the ID. It is in fact attaching to each record by ID. Although you do need a slight adjustment to your `foreach`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Didn't know it'd be that simple! Good Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the method shown by rojoca doesn't work, you could do this:

```
$records = $sql->result_array();
```

Then loop through as usual (except do `$record_id = $record['record_id']` instead of `$record->record_id`), and reference your row like this:

```
$records[$record_id]['threads'] = $threads;
```

Though you may not want to rely so heavily on that record_id column always matching perfectly with your iteration index.